# Generate WPF Mouse events with position

Tags: wpf, testing, automation, mouseevent

I'm trying to create a more-or-less high-level UI test for a WPF control (but without the complexities of UI Automation – UIA works, but I'd rather avoid it if possible), and found `RaiseEvent` and `InputManager.ProcessInput` for synthesizing input events. What I couldn't figure out, though, is how mouse (and touch) events can be created with a particular position. `MouseEventArgs` has a `GetPosition` method that *returns* the position for the event, but how can I set it?

The reason why I avoided UI Automation here is two-fold: (1) I want the tests to run headless, if possible, thus injecting events instead of simulating mouse movement; (2) I need to test touch input as well, for which I didn't find a library to simulate them so far.

I tried inheriting from `MouseDevice` only to find that there are no virtual methods that are of use to me here, so that seems a dead end as well.

Comment: I've tried scanning a little in the source code, the `GetPosition()` method will calculate the point based on many parts, so it's hard to inject and change something to make it return whatever you want. If you mean you want to change the mouse position programmatically, try using some Win32 API functions, such as `SetCursorPos`... The info of position should be the actual position of the mouse, so of course we cannot change it easily.

Comment: Added a bit of rationale. The problem with `SetCursorPos` is that it tries moving the actual mouse cursor, which won't work in a locked session.